# Why is gam::step.gam returning NULL with forward selection?

Tags: r, gam

I have a large Generalized Additive Model (GAM) made from 10K observations with ~ 100 variables.  Building the model with forward stepwise selection results in an object of class "NULL".  Why might this be and how do I resolve it?

```
library(gam)

load(url("https://github.com/cornejom/DataSets/raw/master/mydata.Rdata"))
load(url("https://github.com/cornejom/DataSets/raw/master/mygam.Rdata"))

myscope <- gam.scope(mydata, response = 3, arg = "df=4") #Target var in 3rd col.
mygam.step <- step.gam(mygam, myscope, direction = "forward")

mygam.step
NULL
```

The code that was used to fit `mygam` from `mydata` is:

```
library(gam)

#Identify numerical variables, but exclude the integer response.
numbers = sapply(mydata, class) %in% c("integer", "numeric")  
numbers[match("Response", names(mydata))] = FALSE 

#Identify factor variables.
factors = sapply(mydata, class) == "factor"

#Create a formula to feed into gam function.
myformula = paste0(paste0("Response ~ ", 
                          paste0("s(", names(mydata)[numbers], ", df=4)", collapse = " + ")
                          ),
                   " + ",
                   paste0(paste0(names(mydata)[factors], collapse = " + ")))

mygam = gam(as.formula(myformula), family = "binomial", mydata)
```

Comment: I thought perhaps this had to do with using variables with insufficient number of unique values to honor the degrees of freedom requested in the spline representations. So, I eliminated such variables with less than 15 unique values from the **scope** argument to `step.gam` ... but got same results.  Perhaps they need to be removed from the original call to `gam`.  If so, it's surprising to not have received a warning of some sort (as is done in the mgcv package).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the issue is with the `mygam` object.

#### Explanation

If you read the `help(step.gam)` it has this paragraph in the explanation of `scope` argument:

> The supplied model ‘object’ is used as the starting model,
>     and hence there is the requirement that one term from each of
>     the term formulas be present in ‘formula(object)’. This also
>     implies that any terms in ‘formula(object)’ *not* contained
>     in any of the term formulas will be forced to be present in
>     every model considered. The function ‘gam.scope’ is helpful
>     for generating the scope argument for a large model.

In essence this says that the first argument passed to `step.gam` function (`mygam` in this case) will have a formula and that formula will be used as a starting model for the stepwise procedure.

Since here we have **forward** stepwise - it cannot start from the full model, because in that case there is nothing left to add.

#### Exploring The Code

This idea is reinforced if we look at the code. The code of `step.gam` function has this loop that runs in case of **forward** selection.

```
if (forward) {
    trial <- items
    trial[i] <- trial[i] + 1
    if (trial[i] <= term.lengths[i] && !get.visit(trial,
      visited)) {
      visited <- cbind(visited, trial)
      tform.vector <- form.vector
      tform.vector[i] <- scope[[i]][trial[i]]
      form.list = c(form.list, list(list(trial = trial,
        form.vector = tform.vector, which = i)))
    }
}
```

Notice that the loop executes only when the inner if statement is TRUE. And that if statement seems to check if you have potential variables in your scope (`term.length`) that are not yet in your model (`items`, `trial`). If you don't - the loop skips.

Since in your case the loop never executes it doesn't form the return object and the procedure returns NULL.

#### The Solution

Given all the above - the solution is to not start with the complete formula when using **forward** selection method. Here for the demonstration I will be using the intercept-only model as a starting model:

```
library(gam)
load(url("https://github.com/cornejom/DataSets/raw/master/mydata.Rdata"))
mygam <- gam(Response ~ 1, family = "binomial", mydata)
```

The last line is the only change that needs to be made. Everything else is the same as in the original post:

```
myscope <- gam.scope(mydata, response = 3, arg = "df=4")
mygam.step <- step.gam(mygam, myscope, direction = "forward")
```

And now the procedure works.